# Photoshop scripting: layerSets.length not counting all layerSets

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm trying to count all my layerSets at the top level, using this code: `

```
alert ("Total top-level groups:  " + app.activeDocument.layerSets.length);
```

This works of course, but it fails if the top-most layerSet has only one child layer. Here's one that works:

[image: two layers in top layerSet]

BUT, if I move Group 2 to the top, it no longer works:

[image: One layer in top layerSet]

If I add a second layer to Group 2, it works again:

[image: Two layers in top layerSet]

Why doesn't `layerSets.length` count a layerSet when there's only one layer in it? It's still a layerSet...

### UPDATE (Jan 2, 2020):

I think it may have to do with the Mac OS... I have 2 computers with the same version of PS (22.1.0). This script works with Catalina (10.15), but not with Mojave (10.14).

If anyone else can test this, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: I can't reproduce this (I'm getting the expected values) on 2021, 2020, 2019. Is this code a part of a bigger script?

Comment: I want it to be part of a bigger script, but for now I'm just testing it with this one line.

What version of PS are you using? I just tested this on another computer: It works on PS 22.0.0 (Mac OS Catalina). The example I posted above is PS 22.1.0 (Mac OS Mojave).

Comment: Tried on 22.1.0 and 22.0.0 (Catalina) and it works. I don't have Mojave so can't test it